# Bigtable do not automatically break lines of text containing dots

Tags: longtable

I'm working with a PDF report from data received from an application and recorded into a formated .tex LaTeX file.
The aim of this report is to present data as a long table, which can span over several pages.
Until now everything is working fine, except the cells having hostnames that naturally have dots, for example, myhost.mydomain.example.com.
The **uid** column do not automatically breaks the text if the hostname have dots. When I replace the dots by a dash, for example, the automatic line breaking works fine.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,includeheadfoot,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\clearpage
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{id} & \textbf{mac} & \textbf{uri} & \textbf{ip} & \textbf{netdevip} & \textbf{netdevport} & \textbf{netdevportid} & \textbf{netdevmac} & \textbf{ssid} & \textbf{uid}\\ \hline
\endhead

000000000002&00:00:00:00:00:02&c181af20-5594-11e8-bb9e-6e6163636f72&200.200.200.201&200.200.200.200&50004&FastEthernet0/4&00:00:00:00:00:01&&\\ \hline                                                                                                                       
000000000003&00:00:00:00:00:03&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.1&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&&myhostname.mysubdomain.mydomain.example.com\\ \hline                                                                                                                        
000000000004&00:00:00:00:00:04&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.2&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&&otherhostname.mysubdomain.mydomain.example.com\\ \hline                                                                                                                     
000000000005&00:00:00:00:00:05&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.3&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&&\\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image: Cells with hostnames having dots]

Outuput replacing dots by dashes:

[image: Cells with hostnames having dashes]

Any help to understand this behavior and solve the problem is very welcome!

Comment: this is unrelated to longtable, it is just the normal behaviour that tex will break  a hyphenated word `foo-bar`  but not a number `100.20`

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification @David Carlisle! I had not thought about that and was thinking it was my fault when defined the table.

Answer (score 4):

You can load `xurl` and  use the `\url` command. Here is a code, where I use a `tabularx` environment. Package `ltablexs` brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. I redefined the column specifiers to either `l` or `X`, played with the value of `\tabcolsep` and added some vertical padding to cells with `\setcellgapes...\makegapedcells` from package `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm, vmargin=1cm, includeheadfoot, landscape, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xurl, makecell}
\def\UrlFont{\sffamily}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont%
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|l|X|l|l|l|l|l|p{2cm}|X|}
\hline
\textbf{id} & \textbf{mac} & \textbf{uri} & \textbf{ip} & \textbf{netdevip} & \textbf{netdevport} & \textbf{netdevportid} & \textbf{netdevmac} & \textbf{ssid} & \textbf{uid}\\ \hline
\endhead

000000000002&00:00:00:00:00:02& \url{c181af20559411e8bb9e6e6163636f72} &200.200.200.201 & 200.200.200.200 & 50004 & FastEthernet0/4 & 00:00:00:00:00:01 & & \\
\hline
000000000003&00:00:00:00:00:03&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.1&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&& \url{myhostname.mysubdomain.mydomain.example.com} \\
\hline
000000000004&00:00:00:00:00:04&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.2&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&& \url{otherhostname.mysubdomain.mydomain.example.com}\\
\hline
000000000005&00:00:00:00:00:05&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.3&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&&\\ \hline

\end{tabularx}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernard. Your solution worked fine using a longtable too.

Comment: Fine! Yet I think a breakable tabularx is a better solution here

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you load the `url` package and encase the cell contents in the final column in `\url{...}` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url} % <-- new
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1cm,
            includeheadfoot,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\footnotesize
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  % for a more open "look"
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}       % default : 6pt
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}  |p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|  p{2cm}|p{2cm}|
                   p{1.5cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{id} & \textbf{mac} & \textbf{uri} & \textbf{ip} &
\textbf{netdevip} & \textbf{netdevport} &
\textbf{netdevportid} & \textbf{netdevmac} & 
\textbf{ssid} & \textbf{uid}\\ 
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\endlastfoot

000000000002&00:00:00:00:00:02&c181af20-5594-11e8-bb9e-6e6163636f72&200.200.200.201&200.200.200.200&50004&FastEthernet0/4&00:00:00:00:00:01&&\\
\hline
000000000003&00:00:00:00:00:03&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.1&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&&\url{myhostname.mysubdomain.mydomain.example.com}\\
\hline
 000000000004&00:00:00:00:00:04&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.2&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&&\url{otherhostname.mysubdomain.mydomain.example.com}\\
\hline
000000000005&00:00:00:00:00:05&&0.0.0.0&10.10.10.3&50102&GigabitEthernet1/0/2&00:00:00:00:00:00&&\\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```